# Finding desired search result from list in Txt file with python

Tags: python

```
 def add():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("How many words do you want to add:"))
            if a >= 0:
                break
            else:   
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Not valid ")
    return a
for i in range(add()):
    key_i = input(f"Turkish meaning: {i + 1}: ")
    value_i = input("translated version: ")
    with open('words.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write("'"+key_i+':')+ f.write(value_i+"'"+",")
```

My goal is to create my own dictionary,but I am adding a list into the txt file, so it is added into the txt file like this

```
words = {'araba:kol',
```

but when I search the txt file it gives me the whole list

```
def search():
    while 1:
        search = str(input("Search: "))
        if search not in["exit", "Exit"]:
            with open('words.txt', 'r+') as f:
                line = f.readline()
                while line:
                    data = line.find(search)
                    if not data == -1:
                        print(line.rstrip('\n'))
                        line = f.readline()
                    else:
                        line = f.readline()
        else:
            break
    f.close()
```

What can I do to make it output like this

```
car:araba
```

Comment: If the entire line is a singular string, use the ```.split()``` function to break it up into different values. That should return a list, which you can then print each piece of.

Edit: I forgot to add, you type in the string you want it to split by inside the parenthesis. In this case, use a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON module to avoid having to write the dictionary line by line yourself.

```
import json
with open('words.json', 'a+') as f:
    json.dump({key_i: value_i}, f)

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    d2 = json.load(f)
```

d2 is now the data that you wrote to the file.
Note, that you should change the a+ to 'w' as you only have one dictionary per file.